# Creating a multidimensional array in C++/CLI with an empty dimension size

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am working on converting a C# project to a C++/CLI project. I came across this code and wanted to verify that I am using the proper C++/CLI syntax. I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong, just setting parameters when I want to set the size of the dimensions.

Original C#:

```
public double[][] _ARRAY = new double[num][];
```

C++/CLI:

```
array<double, 2>^ _ARRAY = gcnew array<double, 2>{ {num}, {} };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That IS how you create a multidimensional array in C++/CLI.  But the C# isn't actually a multidimensional array at all.

These two are the same:

```
/* C# */ public double[][] arrayOfArray;
/* C++/CLI */ array<array<double>^>^ arrayOfArray;
```

and so are these:

```
/* C# */ public double [,] array2D;
/* C++/CLI */ array<double,2>^ array2D;
```

A real two-dimensional array can't be half-dimensioned as you show, that's only possible with a jagged array (array of arrays).  For the jagged array, C++/CLI should certainly allow

```
arrayOfArray = gcnew array<array<double>^>(num);
```

which is (just like the C# code in your question) an array of (initially null) managed handles to arrays.