# Converting textbox->text to string

Tags: string, text, textbox, c++-cli

Hey I'm trying to save text entered in textbox as string

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    int IloscBD1=0, IloscBD2=0, IloscPD1, IloscPD2, Suma, I, J, Punkty, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, Druzyna;
    int TabPunkt[10][6];

    std::string TabOdpowiedzi[10][6];

...


...
private: System::Void buttonZ_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    TabOdpowiedzi[1][1] = (Convert::ToString(textPO->Text));
    this->textPN->Text = (Convert::ToString(TabOdpowiedzi[1][1]));
}
```

But I am getting those errors, what's wrong? How can I keep input from text box as a string for future or is there a better way to keeping text input for future usage ?

> Error  1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> Error  2   error C2665: 'System::Convert::ToString' : none of the 37 overloads could convert all the argument types
>
> 3  IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
>               operand types are: std::string = System::String ^
>
> 4  IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "System::Convert::ToString" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (std::string)

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1b4az623.aspx) might help you.

Comment: 1. This is C++/CLI, not C++. Why are you mixing managed and unmanaged code? `std::string` and `System.String` are different types, it's propably easier to pick one and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up your types. Declare

```
std::string TabOdpowiedzi[10][6];
```

As

```
array<System::String^,2>^ TabOdpowiedzi = gcnew array<System::String^,2>(10, 6);
```

And your problems *here* vanish. Maybe you will have problems in other parts of your code then, but you have not posted those...

Comment: Well definition of `System::String^ TabOdpowiedzi[10][6];` generates those errors:

`Error 1 error C2728: 'System::String ^' : a native array cannot contain this type `
 `2 IntelliSense: array of handles is not allowed `

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right, you can find the correct syntax for C++/CLI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163786/creating-a-multidimensional-array-in-c-cli-with-an-empty-dimension-size).